# How to fix "TypeError: window.location is not a function"?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

When I run unit test that contained logic about window.location. I will get this error on my terminal.

TypeError: window.location[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

```
      35 |   localVue.use(VueRouter);
    > 36 |   const router = new VueRouter(...routerOptions);
      37 | 
      38 |   Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => {
      39 |     localVue.filter(key, filters[key]);
```

My sample unit test code that only contain logic regarding window.location

```
   beforeEach(() => {
      global.window = Object.create(window);
      const url = "http://localhost.com";
      Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
        value: {
          href: url
        },
        writable: true
      });
    });
```

Have anyone met this situation?. I really need help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `jest.config.js` you can add a [setup files](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) entry that point to a file with some custom configuration. There, you can declare methods and properties for the `window` object. For instance, your `jest.config.file` could be like:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  'setupFiles': ['./tests/unit/config.main.js'],
  ...
}
```

And then, in the `/tests/unit/config.main.js` (or whatever path), you just add:

`window.location = { value: { href: "http://localhost/" }};`

In my own setup file I also have this `window` helpers, for instance:

```
window.alert = (msg) => { console.log(msg); };
window.matchMedia = () => ({});
window.scrollTo = () => { };
```

So code in your app that call those `window` methods does not break the test.

(I actually never tried to setup `window.location` in a setup file, but this should work straight).

Comment: I have moved my code to setup.js file. `global.window = Object.create(window);
Object.defineProperty(global.window, "location", {
  value: {
    href: "http://localhost/"
  },
  writable: true
});` and it work well. Thanks.